# Change one cs file in C# dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have no idea about C# programming.

My problem is that I have one DLL file consisting of many .cs files. One method implemented in one of those .cs files is written poorly and slowing down the whole application. I tried to decompile whole DLL with NET Reflector and succeed but with 14 errors. Then I improved my one .cs file and tried to compile all .cs back to .DLL once again. As you suspect, I ended with more that 100 compilation errors in Visual Studio. I assume this is happening because of poor quality of the decompiled code.

Is there anything that I can do with it without spending 1000 hours to learn C#, understanding all 10MB of source .cs files, rewriting them and compiling back to DLL?

Comment: I don't think decompiled code is compilable at all. Their main purpose is for viewing the algorithm in general. You can try real RE techniques to patch that dll? and btw I don't think it's legal to decompile proprietary dll.

Comment: Trying to modify software if you don't have the source is not an exercise for the uninitiated. And if you don't actually know any C# (or IL), it's a fool's errand. The sanest thing you can do is go back to wherever the software is coming from and ask them to improve it.

Comment: I would question if you are actually correct about the quality and speed of that method. How do you know? If that method is, for instance, making database calls maybe your queries or indexes are slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you still looking to change dll, instead of extending the class,
you can use **IL spy with reflexil**.

- this allows you to change the dll and save it.
- you can make small changes to the DLL easily.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I WILL GIVE IT A TRY! <3

Answer (score -1):

You can't change a .cs-File in a DLL, because a DLL does not consist of files, but IL code instead - at least, when you talk about a .Net-Library.

You can decompile the DLL, change the code and recompile it, but decompiled code probably won't be able to be compiled again, depending on what exactly the original code contained.

If there is no source available for the DLL, you will probably not be able to change the way a DLL behaves.

You may try to extend the class in a DLL by inheritance and use your "Updated version" instead.

Comment: Thank you! I tried searching google throughly but haven't found anything relevant about extending the class in DLL by inheritance. Could you provide me with some more details how can I do this or where I can found some more info?

Comment: You simply create a new class and inherit from the class you want to extend. Just add variables, properties, methods and events as you like.